# Deleted /usr/bin/touch and /bin/touch. Can't seem to install anything now, nor create any files?

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg, touch

After updating GNOME to 3.20.2 I had some problems with my touchpad so in that confusion I mistakenly **deleted /usr/bin/touch** and after that I even became more stupid and **deleted /bin/touch.**

Now after this I can't seem to install any of the programs. 
Here's the error generated in installing a program..

```
user1@pqrx:~$ sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0
[sudo] password for user1: 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gir1.2-gtop-2.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/54.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 104 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package gir1.2-gtop-2.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 351267 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-gtop-2.0_2.34.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-gtop-2.0:amd64 (2.34.0-1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-gtop-2.0:amd64 (2.34.0-1) ...
sh: 1: touch: not found
update-kali-menu: error: Can't open /var/lock/kali-menu: No such file or directory
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke '[ ! -x /usr/share/kali-menu/update-kali-menu ] || /usr/share/kali-menu/update-kali-menu wait_dpkg'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was very thankful for all the valuable time you guys spent answering my question and combining both the answers I found the best solution.

IF you have messed up with the **coreutils** then the best thing to do is download the **coreutils** file from the repository.
As we all know that **.deb files are basically archive**, open it with the **file-roller** and extract the package and replace the necessary files, set the required permissions and reboot.

Its done.

Answer (score 6):

`touch` is included with the [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html). Since you deleted the program, you can use this command to attempt to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

Using only this command reinstalled deleted `/usr/bin/touch` and `/bin/touch` programs on a fresh install of Kali Linux 2016.1.

For other distributions, notably Mint (tested on 17.3 Cinnamon), running `sudo apt-get update` first may be necessary.

In general, one can determine which package is involved by searching `dpkg` for a file name in question, in your case:

```
dpkg -S bin/touch
```

Answer (score 4):

You can work around (most) uses by making a shell script `/bin/touch`, and using that to repair your system enough to reinstall the package containing the actual executable.

Some applications will use `touch` to set timestamps.  That is harder in a shell script.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in "$@"
do
    chmod +w "$name"
    printf '' >> "$name"
done
```

Comment: If the system has `busybox`, then wrapping `busybox touch "$@"` might be another option?

Comment: or just a symlink to busybox.

Comment: It might, although it seems that busybox is most often discussed in terms of its differences from other utilities.